# Cantor Function Question

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for an explicit expression for the Cantor function for points in the cantor set. Does anyone know of one?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean explicit?

Comment: Do you mean something more explicit than *replace each* $2$ *in the ternary expansion by a* $1$ *and interpret the result as a binary expansion*?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm guessing that he might mean the following. Some analysis textbooks define the Cantor function by defining it as constant pieces outside the Cantor set (in the open intervals that were removed at each step), and then inside the Cantor set by limits. In this case, you don't get any expression of the function inside the Cantor set, but only in its complement.

Comment: I hope he is not looking for cantor pairing function.

Answer (score 4):

As Brian was alluding to, the canonical [Cantor Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is discussed/defined at the linked Wikipedia entry. You'll find the following algorithm for the function:

> Formally, the Cantor function $c : [0,1] → [0,1]$ is defined as follows:

```
Express x in base 3.
If x contains a 1, replace every digit after the first 1 by 0.
Replace all 2s with 1s.
Interpret the result as a binary number. The result is c(x).
```

...And some alternative definitions.

Comment: Congrats for 1,000 answers.

Answer (score 2):

Define the Cantor function $ f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1] $ as follows.

Let $ x\in [0,1] $.

Then $$ x= \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{a_n}{3^n}\text{ ; where }a_{n}\in \{0,1,2\}\text{ for each } n\in \mathbb{N}. $$

If $ x\in C $ then $ x $ can be written as of the form $$ \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{a_n}{3^n}\text{ ; where }a_{n}\in \{0,2\}\text{ for each } n\in \mathbb{N} $$ and then we define $$ f(x)=f(\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{a_n}{3^n})=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{a_n}{2^{n+1}}. $$

If $ x\notin C $ then there exists $ n_{0}\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ a_{n_{0}}=1 $.

Put $ N=\min \{n_{0}\in \mathbb{N}:a_{n_{0}}=1\} $.

If $ N=1 $ then define $$ f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2} $$ and otherwise we define  $$ f(x)=f(\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{a_n}{3^n})=\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N-1}  \frac{a_n}{2^{n+1}}+\dfrac{1}{2^{N}}. $$